# Is Polymer 3 & Cordova Compatible?

Tags: cordova, polymer-3.x

I cant seem to get even the simple polymer starter kit running with Cordova, If i go back to polymer 2 it works fine, but polymer 3 wont load the my-app page.

I've tried allot of ideas to no avail, Ive added each of the default builds without service workers, I've tried changing the default path to `./` instead of just '/' ive included the links the cordova.js and called app.initalise()

any help would be most appreciated

Comment: We are planning to migrate from Polymer 2 -> 3 and will shortly test out our cordova pipeline. I’ll post here when we have tried it out.

Comment: A small comment: when we worked to get Polymer 2 to work with Cordova we focused first to get the build artifact to work in the browser if serving from file://PATHTOINDEXHTML, it will provide you with plenty of hints to where things go wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to pack a polymer 3 project into cordova, but the problem is that it has to be able to run without a server, because of the CORS policy, It doesn't allow to import ES6 modules unless they are served, so you hace to workaround maybe with webpack or a cordova plugin named CorHttpd for cordova

Comment: Do you have details on how to implement that work around? While it's nice to suggest a direction, it's far more useful to provide detailed instructions.